# Eigen Map - does it take ownership of the data pointer?

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm creating a Matrix with the `Map` class:

```
float* d = new float[rows*cols];
// ... getting data into d
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf>(d, rows, cols);
```

My question is - does `Map` take ownership of the data pointer and deletes it when its done? or does it copy the data and should I free it myself after the Map is created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is very sparse on this but apart from that it's more common to *not* delete what you have not created, posts like [this one](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=85503) suggest **you should delete** d when you're ready.

I suggest to run a memory profiler like `valgrind` which would tell you in case the pointer has not been deleted.

In case you don't delete d `valgrind` reports:

```
400 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
  in operator new[](unsigned long) in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
  1: operator new[](unsigned long) in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
  2: main in test
```

So you can be quite sure you have to delete your data (which is good).

Shame on that documentation...

Comment: I tried now to delete the pointer and print the matrix after I delete it. The data still seems to be there so I assume Map copies the data.

Comment: too bad there is no documentation about this, it's an important issue.

Comment: @Ran did you tried reallocating and assigning something to `d` before printing the matrix ?

Comment: I tried again this instead of deleting I used `memset` to put zeros in the pointer and the data in the matrix was still there. So as @frans said, I should delete the pointer.

Answer (score 6):

No, `Map` does not take ownership so you are still responsible for freeing memory. Actually, the contrary would be impossible for several reasons:

- `Map` cannot know how the memory has been allocated
- You can map only a subrange of an allocated buffer

Moreover, the following would be very strange:

```
 float *d = new float[10];
 // ...
 VectorXf v = ...;
 v = v + Map<VectorXf>(d,10);
 // now d is a dead pointer
```

No way!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't find this option very strange. I encountered several APIs that take ownership of the pointer and manage it. It actually happens a lot with the C++11 move constructor.